# Angular 2+ Replace the parameter in the URL when changing manually by the user in the adress bar

Tags: angular, resolve, route-parameters

I have URL which takes three parameters like
localhost:4200/website/param1/param2/pagename/param3?user=userid

If the user changes either of the parameters and its not valid  , eg: `localhost:4200/website/newparam1/newparam2/pagename/param3?user=userid` i want to redirect them back to valid url `localhost:4200/website/param1/param2/pagename/param3?user=userid`

I have created the service to validate and return proper id for all these parameters. 
so here i am not able to replacing the param's in URL with the right value on load rather than redirect/naviagte.

I have tried to dynamically redirect in component with the below code.
`this.route.navigate("[relativepath,param1, param2,pagname,configid]",{queryparams})`

But this will show the transition from wrong url and to the right one. i want all this to happen on load, like on resolve on route which inturn calls the service.

My service has

```
  createPram1(): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.parameter1);
  }

  createParam2(param1: string): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.param2);
  }

  validateParam1(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.param1=== id ? id : this.param1);
  }

  validateParam2(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.param2=== id ? id : this.param2);
  }
```

My Resolve.ts

```
export class AppPathResolve implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private Service: Service) { }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
     const paramOne= route.paramMap.get('param1');
     if (paramOne=== null) {
         return  this.Service.createPram1();
     } else {
         return this.Service.validateParam1(param1);
     }
  }
}
```

I have searched many links and i the answers dint match my requirement, finally posting it here , hoping to get some info here. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If your redirected URL is not proper while redirecting, use ResponseInterceptor to intercept your request and redirect it to preferred URL.

```
export class ResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor() { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const toaster = this.injector.get(ToasterService);
    return next.handle(req)
        .map(response => {
            return response;
        }).catch(exception => {
                switch (exception.status) {
                    case '404': // you can put any status you want
                        toaster.showErrorMessage(any message to display);
                        this.router.navigate([write your preferred path location here]); // this will redirect you to specific URL
                        break;

                }
            return Observable.of(exception);
        });
}
```

}

Comment: sorry i have never used http interceptors , just went through it and am confused how and when and where to use it. will research more on you solution and see.

Comment: @DpGp take a look and I am sure this code will help you to redirect your URL.

Comment: can we navigate from the current path , here i need to change only the parameter of the current path and not create new on , is there any builtin function where i can get the current path and just replace the parameters with it.

Comment: you can find current URL through this.router.url

Comment: actually i used next.url[] as route.url returns "/"

Answer (score 2):

Resolvers are ideally used to fetch some data for the component before it loads. If you want to prevent a user from entering a URL use Route Guards instead.

```
{path: "website/:param1/:param2/pagename/:param3", component: YourComponent, canActivate: [ParamCheckGuard]}


@Injectable()
export class ParamCheckGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private service: Service, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      const paramOne= next.paramMap.get('param1');
      if (paramOne=== null) {
          return  this.service.createPram1().pipe(map((newParam) => {
                        // form a valid URL and navigate()
                        return false
                    })
                  )
      } else {
          return this.service.validateParam1(paramOne).pipe(map((newParam) => {
                       if (paramOne == newParam) {
                          // it is a valid param.
                          return true
                       }
                       // form a valid URL and navigate()
                       return false;
                   })
                 )
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: dont want to prevent them ,consider a scenario of bookmarking the URL, when user loads the bookmarked page after long time, the specific paramter is id destroyed so in that case we will be generating a new one from the service. and wat to load the URLwith the new param that was generated.

Comment: thanks @xyz, newUrl you have used will contain only param , for which navigateByUrl() maynot work,   but this does not seem to work if the url is invalid in else case, it again blocks the current url.

Comment: @DpGp If the URL is invalid then it will stay at the current URL (If the current URL is a valid URL then it will stay there). If you are not at the valid URL already then get the valid URL first and then navigate to it, just like I have done in the `if` block

Comment: jfyi,  validateParam will not return boolean value , it returns a valid parameter. so in case of invalid url i need to replce current pram with valid one and navigate. so would canActivate work if i dont return true.fase after that? dont want to stay on the current url even if its invalid

Comment: @DpGp Great, then you can use it to navigate to correct URL

Comment: @DpGp You can return an Object in ValidateParam1, which also contains the valid flag., if it is valid then simply return true, if not the use the parameter to navigate to correct  URL. **Edit** Or esle, do a check if the returned param is same previous param then return True

Comment: another favour please, i dont want to use pipe , want to use observable and  forgot to mentioned i tried this before with pipe and my senior dint want me to use pipe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194870/discussion-between-xyz-and-dpgp).